# Can not deploy my contract when i use estimateGas()

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I can not deploy my contract when I use estimateGas() actually estimateGas() and the gasUsed in error is the same. Why does this happen? How to fix this problem?

my code:

```js
const deployedContract = await deployTx.send({
            from: signer.address,
            gas: await deployTx.estimateGas(),
        }).once("transactionHash", (txhash) => {
            console.log(`Mining deployment transaction ...`);
            console.log(txhash);
        });
```

error:

```js
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0x6330753afbeae8ac63fc4056d9f26ea8eec15cfcf6a4cfcf34f4fd2ada55620c',
    blockNumber: 10781483,
    contractAddress: '0x2801e146eB41339F060BbF2b2dd87cE970e5cAec',
    cumulativeGasUsed: 5421372,
    effectiveGasPrice: 4154546093,
    from: '0xa458b7e161aa47c268053004fd0b25b7a2fa66f0',
    gasUsed: 2442757,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: null,
    transactionHash: '0x9e5f0d788ce28e3f5d35ee80e911d3f23f984d3d7d98271e82582b6045534acc',
    transactionIndex: 11,
    type: '0x2',
    events: {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in your code.

The contract has been successfully deployed to the address `0x2801...` shown in the `contractAddress` property of the transaction receipt.

`estimateGas()` just asks the node that you're connected to (in your case most likely a local emulator) to estimate how much gas is the transaction going to cost.